# Link not opening in React admin's list - makes edit instead

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a Resource of campaigns; **id** field of each campaign linked to a standalone page of URLs, belonging to that campaign. (I still don't know how I'll do it).

I use custom field

```
import { useRecordContext, useGetOne } from 'react-admin';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default  () => {

    const campaign = useRecordContext();
    const { data, isLoading } = useGetOne('campaign', { id: campaign.campaign_id });
    const campaignUrlsPage = `/campaign/${campaign.id}/urls/`;
    return /*isLoading ? null : */ <Link to={campaignUrlsPage}>{campaign.id}</Link>;

};
```

Why I commented out **isLoading**? Strange thing but it's always true, after all I don't notice any artefact that way.

Links are shown in the corresponding ceils, thay are actually ancor tags, but clicking them causes record edit. Yes, I have **rowClick="edit"** and I really need it.
Additionally, I have UrlField in the grid, and clicking it first shows record edit page but next it directs to the URL.
Can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's impossible. I removed rowClick from DataGrid and display 2 buttons: edit & urls.

Comment: The `/campaign/${campaign.id}` route is set internally by React Admin to be the route for the Edit page of the 'campaign' resource. You need to put your destination page in a custom route to avoid this, e.g. `/custom_route/campaign/${campaign.id}/urls/`

Answer (score 2):

To support `rowClick="edit"`, each datagrid row has a click handler.

If you put your button in a datagrid, when users click on the button, the click even propagates down to the datagrid row, and the row click event handler fires.

So you must stop event propagation in your link:

```
export default  () => {

    const campaign = useRecordContext();
    const { data, isLoading } = useGetOne('campaign', { id: campaign.campaign_id });
    const campaignUrlsPage = `/campaign/${campaign.id}/urls/`;
    return isLoading ? null : (
        <Link 
            to={campaignUrlsPage}
            onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
        >
            {campaign.id}
        </Link>
    );

};
```